# Batch File extension chanage

Tags: cmd

I am having to change a the file extension of some 800 files from .doc to .htm. I have tried using the ren command in the command line with ren *.doc *.htm

The file extension changes but when I to open the file I get a wall of useless text. If I change the change the file extensions though word using the Save As function it works but since I have 800 files I want to know if there is some way I can get the files to work after using the ren command instead.

Answer (score 0):

> The file extension changes but when I to open the file I get a wall of useless text.

That is because the contents of a .doc file are not the same as the contents of a .htm file. The former contains RTF formatted text, while the later contains HTML.

You need to convert the contents from RTF to HTML, which is what SaveAs does for you.

There are a number of online and offline tools that can do that conversion, or you can automate it by scripting Word.